# Can I skip git add command in my next commit?

Tags: git, github

I have a file name is `README.MD`.

I was edited `README.MD` and if I want to commit `README.MD` if so the first I need to run

```
git add README.MD
git commit -m 'first commit'
```

And I was second edited to `README.MD` if so I also too run like above command. So, Can I skip `git add README.md` in my next commit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
git commit -am 'made a change'
```

The `a` flag commits all modified files since the last commit (even those that have not had `git add` run on).

Note: It does not commit untracked files, so you will still need to `git add` any new files you create, the first time you commit them.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use.

`git commit README.MD -m "Made a Change"`

This is used when the file **is already in the repository**. It allows the user to write a different comment for each committed file. I find this useful.